# Problems using a StringBuilder to construct HTML in C#

Tags: c#, html, escaping

I have this line of code that forms an html string:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append("<a href='#' onclick=");
builder.Append((char)22); //builder.Append('\"');
builder.Append("diagnosisSelected('" + obj.Id + "', '" +obj.Name + "')");
builder.Append((char)22);
builder.Append(" >" +  obj.Name + "</a>");
```

In the browser I get

```
<a href='#' onclick=\"diagnosisSelected('id', 'text')\" >some text here</a>
```

and I get an error because of \". How can I output a "?

Comment: I think part of your trouble is that `"` has the ASCII value 0x22 (hexadecimal), not 22 (decimal).

Comment: What is the value of diagn.Name gives that output? My first guess would be "text", but that doesn't seem consistent with the link text. Are you sure this code is running?

Comment: The problem was in IE :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's funny how many times I see people use StringBuilder yet completely miss the point of them. There's another method on StringBuilder called AppendFormat which will help you a lot here:

```
builder.AppendFormat("<a href='#' onclick=\"foo('{0}','{1}')\">{2}</a>", var1, var2, var3);
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: or @"<a href='#' onclick=""foo('{0}','{1}')"">{2}</a>" if the backslashes look as goofy to you as they do to me.

Comment: I'm not a fan of the doubled-up quotes simply because it annoys resharper too much :)

Comment: AppendFormat is useful when the goal is to insert formatted string at the end of current "builder" string value, but what to do to insert formatted string at the beginning ?
I am using builder.insert(0,str) so in this case how to add str as formatted html string?

Answer (score 5):

Use a \"

Quotes are special characters, so they have to be "escaped" by putting a backslash in front of them.

i.e. instead of

```
builder.Append((char)22);
```

use

```
builder.Append("\"");
```

Comment: a pass the string as a Json, and the result is still \", and i had the same error when appending \"

Comment: In that case it could be that something between building the string and emitting it to the output HTML is 'escaping' the quotes for you. It's probably best if you post the code you're using to output the text so people can try to see where it may be being escaped.

Answer (score 2):

Inside of a double quoted string, a `\` is an escape character. To insert just a `"`, you would use `"\""`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the following line:

builder.Append((char)22);

with

builder.Append("\"");