# Dynamic html table in c# with href as edit

Tags: c#, html

**Im trying to loop through a dataset that is converted dynamically to html table but i need to
to represent one column as an edit hyperlink  `<a href="xxxx" Edit /a>`** *i get an error on my example below "system.data.datacolumn  does not contain a public definition for getenumerator*" , the dataset in the datable is too large to represent each row in html thus i have to use foreach loops to create the tables. please assist, if using a asp repeater is easier please provide me with a simpler example.

```
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        strBuilder.Append("<table id='MainTable'  border='1px' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' ");
    strBuilder.Append("style='border: solid 1px Silver; font-size: x-small;'>");

    //Add the headings row.
    strBuilder.Append("<thead>");
    strBuilder.Append("<tr align='left' valign='top'>");

    foreach (DataColumn myColumn in dt.Columns)
     {
        strBuilder.Append("<td align='left' align='top'>");
        strBuilder.Append(myColumn.ColumnName);
        strBuilder.Append("</td>");
     }
```

This is where i need help?

---

```
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Columns[0])
    {

         strBuilder.Append("<a href="+ row.ToString()+">Edit</a>");

    }
```

---

```
    strBuilder.Append("</tr>");

    strBuilder.Append("/<thead>");

    strBuilder.Append("<tbody>");
    //Add the data rows.
    foreach (DataRow myRow in dt.Rows)
    {
        strBuilder.Append("<tr align='left' valign='top'>");

        foreach (DataColumn myColumn in dt.Columns)
        {
            strBuilder.Append("<td align='left' valign='top'>");
            strBuilder.Append(myRow[myColumn.ColumnName].ToString());
            strBuilder.Append("</td>");
        }

        strBuilder.Append("</tr>");

    }

    strBuilder.Append("</tbody>");


    strBuilder.Append("</table>");
```

Comment: try looking at this example which uses `StringBuilder.appendformatter`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970940/problems-using-a-stringbuilder-to-construct-html-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
foreach (DataRow myRow in dt.Rows)
{            
    strBuilder.Append("<tr align='left' valign='top'>");

    //col[0] as link
    strBuilder.Append("<td align='left' valign='top'><a href="+ myRow[0].ToString()+">Edit</a></td>");

    foreach (DataColumn myColumn in dt.Columns.Skip(1)) //skip first, render rest
    {
        strBuilder.Append("<td align='left' valign='top'>");
        strBuilder.Append(myRow[myColumn.ColumnName].ToString());
        strBuilder.Append("</td>");
    }

    strBuilder.Append("</tr>");
}
```